# Highlight new feature in Android

Tags: android

I saw this feature in a lot of apps:

[image]

That is, a highlight "circle" pointing to a new feature in the app.

Is there an official component to achieve this or must I use external libs/ implement myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please refer  [this library](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView)

i hope it's helpful to you ...!

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Feature Discovery](https://material.io/guidelines/growth-communications/feature-discovery.html#feature-discovery-design).  Not sure that there are any inbuilt classes for that but there are tons of libs on [android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/198)